# How to name Node js workers

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Simple question that I can't find a solution to - is there a way to give names to workers that I initialize in my Node.js app? My target is being able to know in which worker I'm looking while debugging a Node.js application in VS Code (by seeing the worker name instead of `Worker ${X}`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, no:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/56679eb53044b03e4da0f7420774d54f0c550eec/src/inspector/worker_inspector.cc#L28

But you could always try to convince them and submit a PR because the feature appears useful

Comment: Great answer, thanks!
I've created a feature request issue in their GitHub repo, so whoever wants to track it's progress: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41589

Answer (score 0):

You can set a name prop on the worker options:

```
new Worker("./foo.js", {name: "Bar"});
```

This will then show as

> [worker 1] Bar

In the VSCode debugger.

As far as I can tell the feature is completely undocumented - it generates type warnings. I stumbled on it whilst porting code intended for Workers in Chrome devtools; which it's been a feature of for several years.